# how to reuse a CASE in the WHERE?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to do a request that looks like this

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 = CASE
    WHEN field2 = 'something' THEN 'something'
    WHEN field1 IS NOT NULL and field2 IS NULL THEN 'somethingElse'
    ELSE NULL
    END
FROM SomeTable
WHERE field3 IS NOT NULL
```

This results in a syntax error. I have to rewrite the CASE in the WHERE instead of just refering to it. Is there a better way to achieve this ?

And out of curiosity, why is "WHERE field3 IS NOT NULL" refused while for example "ORDER BY field3" would pass ?

Comment: There is no FROM clause, field 3 must be in '' or field3. Except that statement is all right.

Comment: I typed this a little too fast =) I edited, thanks.

Comment: In answer to your last question, this relates to the order in which SQL queries are evaluated. "WHERE" is evaluated before "SELECT", so you therefore can not access the alias. "ORDER BY" is evaluated after, therefore you can... http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-SQL-Query-Order-of-Operations.htm

Comment: Good to know, I never realised that WHERE vas evaluated first, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT field1, 
         field2, 
         CASE
            WHEN field2 = 'something' THEN 'something'
            WHEN field1 IS NOT NULL and field2 IS NULL THEN 'somethingElse'
           ELSE NULL
         END as field3
  FROM your_table
) T
WHERE field3 IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Missing an alias for the derived table though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this approach is that it makes the predicate non sargable. It means that a query that could have been satisfied with a couple of index seeks ends up using a scan.

### setup test tables

```
create table SomeTable
(
id int identity(1,1) primary key nonclustered,
field1 varchar(20),
field2 varchar(20)
)

create clustered index ix on SomeTable(field2, field1)

INSERT INTO SomeTable
SELECT left(name,20),left(name,20)
FROM sys.all_columns
UNION ALL
SELECT 'foo','something'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'bar',NULL
```

### Predicate without CASE

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 = CASE
    WHEN field2 = 'something' THEN 'something'
    WHEN field1 IS NOT NULL and field2 IS NULL THEN 'somethingElse'
    END
FROM SomeTable
WHERE field2 = 'something' OR (field2 IS NULL AND field1 IS NOT NULL)
```

### Predicate with CASE

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT field1, 
         field2, 
         CASE
            WHEN field2 = 'something' THEN 'something'
            WHEN field1 IS NOT NULL and field2 IS NULL THEN 'somethingElse'
           ELSE NULL
         END as field3
  FROM SomeTable
) derived
WHERE field3 IS NOT NULL
```

### Execution Plans

[image: Plan]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT field1, field2, CASE
    WHEN field2 = 'something' THEN 'something'
    WHEN field1 IS NOT NULL and field2 IS NULL THEN 'somethingElse'
    ELSE NULL
    END
FROM SomeTable
WHERE CASE
    WHEN field2 = 'something' THEN 'something'
    WHEN field1 IS NOT NULL and field2 IS NULL THEN 'somethingElse'
    ELSE NULL
    END IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: "I have to rewrite the CASE in the WHERE instead of just refering to it. Is there a better way to achieve this ?"